# redshift sql current_date get_date() performance issue

Tags: sql, performance, amazon-redshift, psql

I would like to know whether using the `current_date` or `get_date()` function on redshift SQL would lower the query performance compared to using '2016-05-05' directly, for example.

Example 1:

> select
>   *
>   from
>   table a
>   where time >= current_date - 1
>   and time < current_date

Example 2:

> select
>   *
>   from table a
>   where time >='2016-05-08'
>   and time < '2016-05-09'

Would example 1 or example 2 have better performance? Or would both have the same?

Hope someone could shed some light on it

Answer (score 0):

I just ran up against this, so I shall share my anecdotal experience:

`select * from table where ts > current_date limit 20` was running for 10+mins before I got impatient and killed it.

`select * from table where ts > '2017-06-08' limit 20` completed in 16s.

table has a sort key on ts, and was freshly analyzed